# how to install CryptoTE

Tags: repository

[CryptoTE instructions for Ubuntu](https://panthema.net/2009/cryptote/linux-binary.html#ubuntu) indicate that `deb` should be invoked.  My 12.04 (Precise) system shows there is no such command.  What's wrong with this installation procedure?

> Import repository public key:
>
> wget -O- https://panthema.net/repo/key.asc | apt-key add -
>
> or with sudo:
>
> wget -O- https://panthema.net/repo/key.asc | sudo apt-key add -
>
> Add binary repository line to /etc/apt/sources.list:
>
> deb http://panthema.net/repo/ubuntu precise main
>
> Update package listings and install the package cryptote:
>
> apt-get update
>   apt-get install cryptote

Note that I had to use `sudo` for `wget` as well as for `apt-key` so there might be an error in that regard.

Comment: What error do you get? I also think `wget` shouldn't be used with sudo.

Comment: No command `deb` found.

Comment: Try adding it directly `sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://panthema.net/repo/ubuntu precise main"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deb is not a command. The given command `deb http://panthema.net/repo/ubuntu precise main` is not the command that will add the source  into `/etc/apt/sources.list`.

Instead it is a line that has to be added to the file `/etc/apt/sources.list`
 You need to edit your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file and add the following line

```
deb http://panthema.net/repo/ubuntu precise main
```

to the end of the file.

Or you can add it `sources.list` from command line using `apt-add-repository` as follows:

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://panthema.net/repo/ubuntu precise main"
```

If you get the error `Cannot add PPA: 'No JSON object could be decoded'` then add it manually.

Then, update your system and then install `cryptoTE` by running

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install cryptote
```